# Change color of a pandas bar graph depending on X-Axis value?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have been trying to change the color of the bars on a graph by the X-Value. The graph was made with a DataFrame that has ['Trimestre','Proovedor','Tipo'] as indexes and ['Cantidad'] as column. The resulting graph is the following.

[image]

I want to paint the bars that have got the key 'Trimestre' = 1,'Trimestre' = 2, etc.

This is the DataFrame from which the graph is created.
[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD7WP.png)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please, can you share a share a sample of the data to reproduce ?

Comment: Sure! I just edited the post and added the Data Frame from which the graph is created.